# Is it possible to narrow the types of overloaded parameters without exhaustively checking each parameter in the function body?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I'd like to define a function which can accept parameters typed in one of two ways. For example:

```
type Fn = {
    (abc: number, def: string): void,
    (abc: string): void,
};
```

Given this type signature, if `abc` is a number, then `def` is a string, and if `abc` is a string, then `def` is not defined. This is clear to humans, but is there any way for Typescript to recognize it? For example, the following implementation fails:

```
const fn: Fn = (abc: number | string, def?: string) => {
    if (typeof abc === 'string') console.log(abc.includes('substr'));
    else console.log(def.includes('substr'));
}
```

because although the type of `abc` has been narrowed, TS doesn't understand that the type of `def` has been determined too, so `def.includes` is not permitted. The grouping of argument types is recognized for *callers* of the function, so the following is forbidden, as expected:

```
fn('abc', 'def');
```

But the overloaded type grouping seems to have no effect inside the function.

When there are only a couple of parameters, it's easy enough to explicitly (and redundantly) type-check each parameter, or use a type assertion for each once one has been checked, but that's still ugly. It gets much worse when there are more than a couple of parameters.

Another problematic redundancy is that each possible argument type needs to be listed not only in the `type`, but also in the function's parameter list. Eg `(abc: number)` and `(abc: string)` in the type definition *also* requires `= (abc: number | string)` in the parameter list.

Is there a better pattern available for function overloading without ditching it entirely? I know of at least two workarounds that *don't* involve overloading:

- Pass an object of type `{ abc: number, def: string } | { abc: string }` instead of multiple separate parameters, then pass the object go through a type-guard
- Use two separate functions for the two different types of parameters

But I'd rather use overloading *if* there's a decent way to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible to a limited extent with TypeScript 4.6's [Control Flow Analysis for Dependent Parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#control-flow-analysis-for-dependent-parameters).

TypeScript can narrow down the types of arguments if the narrowing is done with `===`. (A typeof check doesn't appear to work, at least not yet.)

To tweak the example in the question, if the first argument, when it is a string, is `abc`, has no second argument, that can be detected and narrowed by TypeScript thusly:

```
type Fn = (...args: [number, string] | ['abc', undefined]) => void;
const fn: Fn = (abc, def) => {
    if (abc === 'abc') console.log(abc.includes('substr'));
    else console.log(def.includes('substr'));
}
```

The narrowing of the first argument to `abc` allows TS to infer that in the `else`, the second argument is a string, and not `undefined`.

---

It'd be great if types wider than literals could use this same technique, but they don't work (yet) - the `typeof` check on the first argument fails to narrow the second argument.

```
type Fn = (...args: [number, string] | [string, undefined]) => void;
const fn: Fn = (abc, def) => {
    if (typeof abc === 'string') console.log(abc.includes('substr'));
    else console.log(def.includes('substr'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your approaches can be reasonable: (1) separate function declarations (2) union of object parameters or (3) a function overload like in question.

I would prefer (1), If the caller already has enough information to decide which function has to be called, as this reduces the overall conditional complexity of `fn` body.

(2) makes more sense with a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), so you don't loose excess property checks for the caller. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhATgGwPYEMAmAFdj0C2UAvALABQUVUAPlAN5QDWAlgHaYBcUAROjwBoo6AEYBjbmwCuBEUgDcUTBABm3AM7BE7AOZQAvhWq0Gzdl14iei0RKibtbPYfIVQkKADE2JKAAo8HW54JDQsXHwCAEoSAD4oOFQWTAoKMVQ2TSgVNm5vXwDEHXUY4nj6I2oWFX9A9QA6Vg4SYmJefhiKymNqOvrlFXr2MWQpZXU-AHJ1KREHSajKqn0oCGR1aC6e3qKG2yG2EbGICenZ%20cXu5Yp9IA):

```
type OverloadParam =
    | { kind: "a", abc: number; def: string }
    | { kind: "b"; abc: string }

type Fn = (arg: OverloadParam) => void

const fn: Fn = (args) => {
    if (args.kind === "a") {
        args.def.includes('substr')
    } else {
        args.abc.includes('substr')
    }
}
```

In addition, you don't have to list the types twice both in `Fn` and as part of `fn` signature. I found this [oldie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433273/5669456) here as a reason: only functions with a single overload can apply a contextual type.

With (3) there is no clever way to handle variable function parameters inside the function. TS/JS don't support a function overload implementation like this:

```
function fn(abc: number, def: string): void { }
function fn(abc: string): void { } 
// error (TS): Duplicate function implementation. JS would overwrite the first declaration
```

So you will always have to use a wider type signature with optional parameters and/or union types and narrow these types down inside the function body.