# TypeScript function overload prevent parameter declaration any

Tags: typescript

```
function add(x: string, y: string): string
function add(x: number, y: number): number
// How to prevent any as user can cast x or y as any
function add(x: any, y: any): any {
  return x + y
}

add('Hello ', 'Steve') // returns "Hello Steve"
add(10, 20) // returns 30

// return as number as one parameter is number
const a = add('10' as any, 20)
const b = add(10, '20' as any)

// return as string as one parameter is number
const c = add('10', 20 as any)
const d = add(20 as any, '10')
```

How to **`prevent any`** as user can **`cast x or y as any`**. As c and d result can be **`inconsistent`** and **`unknown`**?

Comment: `as any` type assertions are simply part of the language; you cannot prevent them, just don't use them in your own code.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745527/