# Can typescript infer the types for the parameters of a function wthin the function body

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

So I have a generic function that has two arguments, i used a generic to ensure that the second parameter's type is dependent on the value specified for the first parameter.

1. The Function

```
 selectRequester: <T extends RequesterType>(
    requesterType: T,
    requesterArgs: RequesterArgs[T]
  ) => Requester | null = (requesterType, requesterArgs) => {
    let requester: Requester | null = null;

    if (requesterType === "Axios") {
      requester = new AxiosRequester({
        aBaseURL: requesterArgs.baseURL,
        anAccessKey: requesterArgs.accessKey,
        aSecretKey: requesterArgs.secretKey,
      });
    }

    return requester;
  };
```

2. The Parameter types

```
export type RequesterArgs = {
  Axios: { baseURL: string; accessKey: string; secretKey: string };
  Fetch: { name: string };
};

export type RequesterType = keyof RequesterArgs;
```

When calling the function everything works as expected. Meaning when i enter the first parameter, the second parameter automatically expects the corresponding parameters. For example

Parameter 1 : "Axios"
Parameter 2 : EXPECTS = `{ baseURL: string; accessKey: string; secretKey: string }`

**Problem**

TypeScript is not inferring the type for parameter 2 within the function body. For example when I write an if statement based on the value of parameter 1, typescript is not inferring the type for parameter 2 when writing statements within the body of that if statement.

```
if(parameter1 === "Axios"){
  parameter2.baseURL // This is giving an error
   parameter2.accessKey // This is giving an error
   parameter2.secretKey // This is giving an error
}
```

This is the Error message typescript is throwing at me.

`Property 'baseURL' does not exist on type '{ baseURL: string; accessKey: string; secretKey: string; } | { name: string; }'. Property 'baseURL' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'`

Does anyone have a solution to this problem.

I tried making the key an `enum` instead of generating it from the keys of the `RequesterArgs`, but this still did not work.

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a simplified [mcve] demonstrating the problem that we can copy and paste into our code editors in order to help you. (What is the `Requestor` type, for instance?) Ideally, also provide a link to [the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) with that same code in it showing the errors you're running into. (Sadly, [beware this problem posting playground links in the SO editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386543/why-does-my-typescript-playground-link-break-when-i-use-insert-hyperlink); see the link for a workaround.)

Comment: Is `selectRequester` really supposed to be a function that returns a function?

Comment: You never answered the questions above, but this should get you going the right way: https://tsplay.dev/wRX3xm

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get your example to work (without a cast), but if you don't mind doing things differenty something like this would work:

```
type AxiosArgs = { type: 'Axios', baseURL: string }
type FetchArgs = { type: 'Fetch', name: string }

type RequesterArgs = AxiosArgs | FetchArgs

function foo (args: RequesterArg): void {
  if (args.type === 'Axios')
    args.baseUrl
  } else {
    args.name
  }
}

foo({ type: 'Axios', baseUrl: '...' }) // this is fine
foo({ type: 'Axios', name: '...' })    // this doesn't compile
```

Stolen directly from the official docs about [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

> In this case, *type* was that common property (which is what’s considered a discriminant property of *RequesterArgs*). Checking whether the *type* property was "*Axios*" got rid of every type in *RequesterArgs* that didn’t have a *type* property with the type "*Axios*". That narrowed *RequesterArgs* down to the type *AxiosArgs*.

<sub>In italic the stuff I changed to go with the example above.</sub>

Comment: Here's how to get the OP's code working without a cast: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745527/is-it-possible-to-narrow-the-types-of-overloaded-parameters-without-exhaustively Example: https://tsplay.dev/wRX3xm